# perforce get labeling/tagging history of file

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to investigate the labeling/tagging history of files in perforce and don't see any obvious way to do so. We have a file where someone seems to be accidentally adding our "LATEST" label to an older version of the file, possibly stemming from attempting to add the label to files with a stale copy of the offending file. I can look at the older and newer versions of the file in p4v and see which of them has the label, but I don't see any way of seeing when the label was applied to one version or the other or who made that change. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

With static labels (set via `p4 labelsync`/`p4 tag`) this is difficult -- it is doable by looking at the db journal, or structured server logs, but it's not really a first-class operation and I'd frankly recommend avoiding static labels for anything that needs to be traceable.

Automatic labels (where you set the `Revision` field in the label to a changelist) are less error-prone (assuming that the intent is always to capture a specific point in time rather than a hand-picked assortment of individual file revisions) and can be tracked by running `annotate` in the spec depot.

A step above automatic labels would be to track your LATEST state as a branch -- then each promotion of a revision to the branch happens in a changelist, which really gives you full versioning of that change in state (including easy rollbacks of individual changes), and also allows for hand-picking of individual files since Perforce integration can be done on a per-revision basis.